# Clojurescript - Placeholder in text box

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, luminus

I want to create a textbox in my homepage so I have written the following:

```
(defn home-page []   
    [:div.container    
        [:h1 "Enter Code:"]    
        [c/text-input "id" :id "enter code" fields]])
```

where the c/text-input is contained in another namespace (common.cljs) which I have required.

The code in the common.cljs namespace is the following:

```
(defn input [type id placeholder fields]
  [:input.form-control.input-lg
   {:type        type
    :placeholder placeholder
    :value       (id @fields)
    :on-change   #(swap! fields assoc id (-> % .-target .-value))}])

(defn form-input [type label id placeholder fields optional?]
  [:div.form-group
   [:label label]
   (if optional?
     [input type id placeholder fields]
     [:div.input-group
      [input type id placeholder fields]
      [:span.input-group-addon
       "✱"]])])

(defn text-input [label id placeholder fields & [optional?]]
  (form-input :text label id placeholder fields optional?))
```

However my problem arises where if I remove `[c/text-input "id" :id "enter code" fields]]` from my code the webpage loads as normal. With this line of code in nothing happens.

I cannot figure out my mistake and any help would be appreciated.

(P.S I am using a luminus framework if that is of any help)

Comment: Can you see any error messages on the browser console window?

Comment: I get an error saying fields is an unused argument but I don't know what to put in it's place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you posted, it looks like `fields` should be an `atom` containing a `map` where the value of the field will be stored under the key `id`. The code should look more or less like this:

```
(defn home-page []
  (let fields (atom {})
    [:div.container
      [:h1 "Enter Code:"]
      [c/text-input "id" :id "enter code" fields]]))
```

I hope this proves to be helpful.